# FFMPEG.exe does not recognize devicename

Tags: ffmpeg

A setup with a camera and some sensors, capuring my movement is giving my and error.

> FFMPEG returns a "could not find videodevice"

The camera is a Ximea and the XimeaCaptureTool tell me the devicename = MQ013CG-ON 39313651
FFMPEG is setup for C:\temp for the output and nothing ever shows up in there.

Any ideas on how to debug?

Comment: Well. Not much response here. :-)